# Can I host ASP.Net 5 Application Without HttpPlatformHandler?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I wanted to know that is it possible to host ASP.Net 5 / MVC 6 Application without having HttpPlatformHandler installed on IIS?

Comment: Is there a reason why? We don't want to end up with an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Because not all hosting companies currently support HttpPlatformHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a decision made a few months ago and would never change later until there is another announcement.

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69

Embrace it or you need to have a discussion with Microsoft and a reason to convince them.

**[Updated: For RC2 and above, a new module is required, https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/164]**

Comment: Thank you Lex I have already seen this post, the reason I am asking this is because, not all hosting companies currently support HttpPlatformHandler. And there are certain limitations in new hosting model as mentioned in the post:

The HttpPlatformHandler currently does not forward client certs (this will be a future enhancement)

The raw performance is lower than using Helios in-process.

Comment: @NaveedAhmed you will have to talk to your hosting provider then to get HttpPlatformHandler installed.